# Prevent to type zero as the first digit in value

Tags: c

I have this code that decode the input char from commands

```
    if( arg && isdigit( arg[ 0 ] ) {

        /* Decode the input char from commands.  */
        if( cmd->digit_counter == 0 ) memset( cmd->next_chan_buffer, 0, 5 );
        cmd->next_chan_buffer[ cmd->digit_counter ] = arg[ 0 ];
        cmd->digit_counter++;
        cmd->frame_counter = cmd->delay;

        /**
         * Send an enter command if we type more digits than there are stations.
         */
        if( cmd->digit_counter > 0 && (station_get_max_position( cmd->station ) < 10) ) {
            commands_handle( cmd, ENTER, 0 );
        } else if( cmd->digit_counter > 1 && (station_get_max_position( cmd->station ) < 100) ) {
            commands_handle( cmd, ENTER, 0 );
        } else if( cmd->digit_counter > 2 ) {
            commands_handle( cmd, ENTER, 0 );
        }
    }
```

This count number of digits typed in keypad number and write numbers in a box, for example

```
      |5|4|2|0|
```

I want to prevent first count digit to be 0 (or to accept number only 1 to 9) and second, third, ... digits to accept number from 0 - 9

```
digits count           1            2        3        4
          -------------------------------------------------
          | only digits 1 to 9 | 0 to 9 | 0 to 9 | 0 to 9 |
          -------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

OK, solved by adding function:

```
int first_digit( int num ) 
{
        while(num >= 10) {
            num = ( num - ( num % 10 ) ) / 10;
        }
        return num;
}

if( arg && isdigit( arg[ 0 ] ) {

        /* Decode the input char from commands.  */
        if( cmd->digit_counter == 0 ) memset( cmd->next_buffer, 0, 5 );
        cmd->next_buffer[ cmd->digit_counter ] = arg[ 0 ];
        if( first_digit( atoi( cmd->next_chan_buffer ) ) != 0 ) {
            cmd->digit_counter++;
            cmd->frame_counter = cmd->delay;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the check like this instead of using isdigit().

```
if( arg && arg[0] >= '1' && arg[0] <= '9' ) { // only accept '1' through '9'
```

The characters from '0' to '9' are always in adjacent order in C, so this check does what you need.